# Can't play chess

Tags: the-sims-3

My young adult sim needs to play chess in order to succeed in her life goal. Whenever I call over the next ranked opponent it works, but I can't figure out how to play chess with her. The sims just end up talking and I can't make them actually play chess. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

In order to play Chess in Sims 3, you must have a chess table with two dining chairs next to it.

You need to put the chairs on the side where the arrow is pointing towards to when you try to move the chess table.

Once you set it up, click on it and start a tournament.